# Images in datagridview once more time

Tags: image, datagridview

I need your advice on a rather simple question - I'd like to draw an image in datagridview cell.

The problem is that the number of rows can be rather big: up to 100 000 of rows, sometimes more than that.

I tried using CellFormating but in this case the grid is blinking. I tried to set DoubleBuffered = true but it got only worse - the window hung and CPU usage was showing 100%. Other controls stopped drawing itself. Moreover it did not help blinking too much (even on several rows).

So I tried to use source DataTable and added a column. Than I filled it with images. But it was a fail: app memory grew very fast on a big datatable and it just crashed.

Also I tried using DataSourceChanged event and settings images like row[cell].Value = . It fires but grid works strange: sometimes it shows images, sometimes it does not. I read that you must set underlying data to make this working but it caused memory problems as I wrote.

I changed image to text so far but certainly I'd like to have moe user-friendly UI.

What can I do in this case? Probably I should give up images or change display logic at all? I.e. use virtual mode. I tried to use it long ago but I had some difficulties so I just skipped this way and my grid is working in non-virtual mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I eventually used CellFormatting event. It looks like blinking has gone away without my help. Images are looking fine.